# Hibernate Updating Collection of entities, returning to the user the number of updated entities

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a collection of entities from the database that is shown to the user (web application with Spring). The user can change one or more entities(rows) and submit all his changes together to the server (not one-by-one).

What is the recommended way of updating only the rows that have changed using Hibernate? At the moment I am storing the original collection as a property in the controller and saving only the rows that have been changed by comparing the entities of the collection with the old ones, one-by-one (incrementing a counter that is returned to the user). I suppose that storing the collection on the controller is not a good practice. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I also want to use optimistic locking (automatic versioning) if that makes any difference.